# Private members in Java

Tags: java, visibility

Does the private members in Java differs from other programming language private members? Because I was surprised that I could just pass an Object of some type to compareTo, and then access the private members of that Object without using any getMethod.

E.g.

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>{

    private int bar;

    public Foo() { bar = 1; }

    public int compareTo(Foo o) {
        if(bar == o.bar)
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: In Smalltalk, the boundary for private is not the class, but the object (as expected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I progam Java for a living for 11 years, I was freaked out when I discovered this fact two (!) years ago. I must have read it before, but somehow it never sunk in. I agree that this seems weird at first, but when you think about it a bit longer it makes perfect sense.

What is OO all about? About separation of concerns and information hiding, right? So in your design you always (should) try to avoid having to 'know' about things outside of your own concern, because this equals making assumptions; the things you 'know' at design time might change later on and invalidate the assumption your class is making.

In this case, you are allowing Foo to access another Foo's private bar, which at first feels like 'knowing' about something outside of Foo's concern. But because we are talking about two instances of the exact same class (Foo) this is actually not outside of our concern! If for example we change bar from int to double, we are doing so within the same class, and any compile errors will show up immediately.

Also, imagine that this type of access were prohibited. So what if Foo called its own compareTo, passing 'this' as an argument? Then we would have to forbid a Foo to access it's own private bar? And what about private static fields? That would be very confusing, don't you agree?

A bit long-winded maybe, but I hope you can appreciate that after the first shock, this actually makes sense! (-:

Answer (score 10):

Yes, private members in Java differ from *some* other languages. For example, I don't *think* the equivalent code in C++ would be valid.

On the other hand, it would be valid in C#. There are still some differences between C# and Java in terms of access to private members from enclosing or nested classes, but they're basically similar.

You shouldn't really expect any two languages to have identical behaviour. It's worth consulting the specification of the language you're actually interested in - in this case, it's [section 6.6 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6).

Comment: no, but it kinda crush the idea of having private variable, doesn't it?

Comment: @starcom, Why? You have a private bedroom, I suppose, and nevertheless that deos not mean that you must sleep on the floor. It only means that not anybody may sleep there.

Comment: Well, the `private` has lexical scope, not dynamic. It's a matter of definition and implementation.

Comment: @starcorn: If you can't trust the rest of the code within the same class not to use the data inappropriately, you've already got bigger issues I'd say. It's certainly not the *same* idea as in C++, but that doesn't make it non-useful...

Comment: you're a machine. You'll get the 300k soon, here's 10 more from me! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, scopes are based on classes, not objects. If something is private, it means it is visible to code defined in that class - even if it's a field of an instance, and the code is executing in another instance.

You can perhaps think of objects of the same class as being like twins who share everything with each other, but who will keep most things hidden from everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

> I could just pass an Object of some
>   type to compareTo

You didn't. You passed an object of type Foo to compareTo(). The rules of Java permit access to any member of any Foo inside the Foo class. C++ is more restrictive in that you can only access private members of *your own* Foo.